# Do I need an AsyncTask to stop blocked UI android while filtering data?

Tags: android

I'm searching a way to improve my android UI while filtering, I have a json that I get from an API call.
The json's data example:

```
{
"response":
"body": [
        {"date":"01/2018",
        "sales":"38",
        "soldProducts": [
                    {"id":"XXX",
                     "name":"xxx"},
                    {"id":"XXX",
                     "name":"xxx"}
          },
          {
          "date": "02/2018",
          "sales": "80",
          "soldProducts": [
                    {"id":"XXX",
                     "name":"xxx"},
                    {"id":"XXX",
                     "name":"xxx"}
          }]
```

I store it in a local file (to have at least one version of data in case of connexion problems).
This is happening on the splash screen that's launched on the start of the application.
On the KPI activity, I display KPIs in my UI with multiple tables containing details.
The problem that I have, is that I'm also using a filter for months, I mean when the activity is displayed at the first time when the data treatment is done, it's containing the KPIs for the actual month, but as we want to keep the history, we have two buttons for next and previous months, on click, the data should be refreshed, and here starts the problem. Once clicked on the button, the app takes almost 3 seconds to prepare the KPIs, then display them, on that time, the UI is blocked, is there anyway to improve that please?

Comment: KPI ??/????????

Comment: @blackapps Key Performance Indicators

Comment: Short answer: yes. yes you do.

Answer (score 0):

you can make this wait using progressdialog.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog

Comment: I though about creating asynctask class and put my function's code there, do you mean that? and appearing ProgressDialog on every click will really kill the User Experience part

Comment: Yes, There are nice libraries for progressdialog I think you should use. https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=progressdialog&type=Repositories

Comment: I will try that.